# Help me understand why a flag was declined

Tags: discussion, flags, declined-flags

I recently flagged [this answer to a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8447/what-does-the-flags-enum-attribute-mean-in-c/8526#8526), with a custom flag saying:

> The question is "I don't understand what exactly the [Flags]-attribute does." for C#, this "answer" does not address the question in the slightest

I did that because, reading the question and the answer, I thought that it might really *try* to answer *something*, but not **that** question.

However, the flag was declined with

> flags should not be used to indicate technical inaccuracies, or an altogether wrong answer

But i do not think the answer is wrong... it might be the right answer, but on the wrong question.

Comment: It was a custom flag on the answer with the text I quoted. Maybe it wasn't detailed enough?

Comment: What a mess. There are *tons* of answers to that question that seem to go off on their own tangents while only relating to the question by way of enums and bit flags. I didn't decline your flag, but I'm not sure what I would have done in this case. The answer you flagged isn't the only one that's problematic.

Comment: OK so the answers seem to be just answering the "Anyone could share an example?" portion in the question... maybe that should be edited out.

Comment: Yes, that would make the question clearer.

Comment: But does not answer why you should or should not use a custom flag for these kind of things ;) I'm trying to find a decent meta to explain it, but so far they're quite conflicting in their answers

Comment: Yeah, your flag was incorrect and rightfully declined.  The question asks for examples, and the answer provides an example.

Comment: I see .. I didn't interpret that as the "real" or "main" question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you feel that an answer is incorrect, or otherwise fails to properly or completely answer the question, then the appropriate course of action is to downvote it (and optionally comment on why you feel it is not a good answer).

Answers are not deleted by mods for failing to successfully answer a question.  Mods are not there to judge posts based on their technical merit and evaluate if the answer is *correct* or a *quality* answer to the question.